# Burnt-Out Redstone Torches Re-Ignites Randomly

Tags: minecraft-redstone, minecraft-legacy-console

I have built a simple hopper/dropper "vending machine" as seen in the pictures below:

[image: My device]

Item frame diagram:
[image: Item frame diagram]

When an item goes into the hopper, it activates the comparator which then ignites the redstone torch. The torch then "short-circuits" itself after 8 ticks, causing 8 items to be dispensed. This works as expected in Minecraft 1.9 (Mac/PC edition), but does not function properly in Minecraft Xbox One CU41.

In Xbox One edition, the torch ignites (as expected) when an item is put in the hopper. However, it also ignites randomly every 15 seconds or so.

According to the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_Torch),

> [The redstone torch] will re-activate when it receives a block update (an adjacent block changing its state) or a redstone update which wouldn't normally deactivate the redstone torch.

Neither of the circumstances for re-lighting were being triggered, as I left the device alone. Why is this happening (is this a glitch?) and how do I fix it?

Comment: Based on the setup... I'm not sure how the torch isn't just always on. There is not constant power other than itself to keep itself off and primed to be triggered, so it's always in an infinite loop? The hopper just acts as a reset/trigger but if you're not using it there is nothing keeping the torch off.  (This is just off the top of my head I haven't played in a few months so I'm rusty and mostly asking as clarification. :) )

Comment: @ZealousHypocrites When you first place the dispenser down, it powers the torch (which in turn turns off and starts the cycle). Torches burn out after 8 cycles. Basically it keeps burning itself out.

Comment: @ZealousHypocrites Actually, the diagram is wrong. I didn't include the redstone dust in the item frame diagram! I'm fixing it right now

Comment: Yes... so... why does it /stay/ burned out though? Without power, because it is off, nothing is keeping it off, therefore it will try and turn back on at some point. Once it has power again, it will burn itself out again, but then there will be no power keeping it off. Infinite loop...?

Comment: @ZealousHypocrites Minecraft Wiki: "A redstone torch will "burn-out" when it is forced to change state ... more than eight times in 60 game ticks." That means it is off until a block or redstone update happens.

Comment: Yes. That's... fine. It turns itself off. Yes. However, unless you continue to power it, it will update itself, and turn itself back on, because there is no power keeping it off after it burns itself out.

Comment: @ZealousHypocrites without sounding overly simplistic, that's just how the game works. It burns out after 8 ticks, then stays "dead" until you update an adjacent block, which restarts the cycle. There's nothing fancy about it - that just happens.

Comment: @yummypasta Can I ask is this on a server at all? Also, does this occur even when you are standing next to it (i.e. you don't move for 15 seconds, and it will re-start)?

Comment: That's strange. This has been the behavior on Xbox since the beginning. From my perspective it appears like the PC is the one with the bug. (I played on PC back before repeaters were released/existed. Shortly after they were released I switched to Xbox and never came back.)

Comment: @Ben Yes, on both platforms i tested it on I was not on a server. It doesn't seem to depend if I was moving, because the chunk was loaded the whole time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is standard behavior of the redstone torch. Every now and then it will be triggered by a `random update`.

This is a type of block update which randomly triggers certain blocks. This is also which is used by for example plants growing on farmland or saplings turning into trees.

This used to be a feature in all minecraft versions but it has been removed with one of the latest java versions (I don't know which).

I believe this might be fixed in a future update also for XBox as mojang is trying to make each version compatible with each other. Till then you will have to wait or find another way to create this.

Comment: So I _was_ right. This _is_ the expected behavior.

Comment: yes for certain versions it still is but they are trying out a new system for it

Comment: Well yeah that's fine. Just... "as it is" that "has" been the way it's been for "most" of the time. Statistically speaking, of course. As in I've been playing the game back when it only cost like $8 and repeaters didn't even exist yet. Even back then, and for the entire time up until this point, a redstone torch will NOT stay off unless it has power feeding it. Even IF it burns itself out, it only stays off for a certain number of ticks then checks again if it still has power and will turn itself back on if it doesn't, because its JOB is to be on /unless/ it has power.

Comment: Basically if they make this change it will change /thousands/ of existing redstone contraptions. I hope it doesn't ruin too many of them.

Comment: Note: I can think of one exception. A torch will STAY burned out sometimes depending on chunk loading order, and if your redstone contraption exists on the border of a chunk. It depends on both the location and orientation. Read up on the old North/South glitch we had to use to get single tick differences to open double doors at the same time (again before repeaters existed, and before they just simply patched the doors to work better) for a basic understanding of how that happens.